# Control Back button and Start button in wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7, location, back-button-control

Can a process be in continuation after Back button press or start start button press.
I am using position change event of GeoCoordinateWatcher. I want to work this event still after pressing back or start button.
How can I do?

Answer (score 1):

On hitting the start button the procesl will pause and u can start on your next launch. MeanWhile you can overide the back key process.

```
 protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
 {
   //cancels the navigation.
   e.Cancel = true;
 }
```